# reshape an array of arrays errors : *** IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, reshape, flatten

l have an array or arrays called my_data such that:
**dimension(my_data)=[96,18,36,36,3]** of type `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`

however, `my_data.shape` returns `(96,)` but l expect to get (96,18,36,36,3). After that l tried `my_data[0].shape` which returns `(18,)` rather than (18,36,36,3) and finally  `my_data[0][0].shape` returns (36,36,3).

I'm wondering why l don't get shape of (96,18,36,36,3)

**Why l need that ?**

l would like to reshape my_data to `(96,18,36*36*3)`

**Wha l have tried ?**

```
my_data=my_data.reshape(my_data.shape[0],my_data.shape[1],my_data.shape[2]*my_data.shape[3]*my_data.shape[4])
```

l get the following error :

```
 *** IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: `type` doesn't tell us much.  If it has a `shape` attribute, it is most likely `ndarray` (or subclass).  `dtype` is more diagnostic.  If `shape` is (96,) and you expect something 5d, then the dtype is probably `object`.  With that `shape`, only `[0]` can be used to index it; it is a 1 element tuple.

Comment: Looks like you have an object dtype arrayof 96 elements.  One of those elements is also object dtype with 18 elements.  And one of those is  (36,36,3) numeric array.  How was the array generated?  It may have subarrays of differing lengths.

Comment: definitely, l just checked, some subarrays have different length. It is supposed when flattening to get them all to  3888=36*36*3 however l find some of them  3564,2808. Is there any efficient way to 0-pad  all the subarrays that are different  of 3888 ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not even sure that how did you get to an `np.array` containing `np.array`s inside. However, simple casting should fix it for you if the data is aligned, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np

x = [np.random.randint(1, 100, (2, 3, 4)) for _ in range(2 * 3)]
x = np.array(x)
x.shape
# (6, 2, 3, 4)
```

If the data is not aligned, you should first align it:

```
import numpy as np
x = [np.random.randint(1, 100, (2, 3, np.random.randint(1, 5))) for _ in range(2 * 3)]
print([y.shape for y in x])
# [(2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 1)]
# x = np.array(x) will cause ValueError...


def zero_padding(arr, shape):
    result = np.zeros(shape, dtype=arr.dtype)
    mask = tuple(slice(None, d) for d in arr.shape)
    result[mask] = arr
    return result


x = [zero_padding(y, (2, 3, 4)) for y in x]
x = np.array(x)
x.shape
# (6, 2, 3, 4)
```

Note: a more sophisticated version of this `zero_padding()`, is provided by NumPy's `pad()`, or by [FlyingCircus](https://pypi.org/project/flyingcircus/)'s `num.reframe()`.

Disclaimer: I am the main author of FlyingCircus.